# Detect AKS namespace creation/deletion

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, azure-aks

I want to **detect namespace creation or deletion activity inside my Azure Kubernetes Cluster**.
Is there a way to enable such logs (I prefer almost real time logs) and then detect the creation or deletion events of namespaces ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alert rule with your condition querying Log Analytics. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-alerts#resource-availability) should be good to start. Alternatively explore [admission controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/) and MutatingAdmissionWebhook resource definitions ([AKS supports it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#what-kubernetes-admission-controllers-does-aks-support-can-admission-controllers-be-added-or-removed)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you suggest in which log analytic table namespace create/delete event are stored.